# SQL distinct and count

Tags: sql, count, aggregate, distinct

I have a query where I want to get distinct dates, the phone numbers associated with those dates, and a count of the phone numbers per date.

For example, I have a database with dates and phone numbers and I want the result to be

```
9/2005      5554446666    3
9/2005      4445556666    1
10/2005     1112223333    1
11/2005     2223334444    2
```

I can get the dates and the counts with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, count(phone) AS count
FROM calls
GROUP BY date
```

What I can't seem to get is the phone number the 'count' is counting.  I think I need some sort of aggregate function to get a single instance of the list of unique values but First() and a few others only throw a SQL error.  Do I need a subquery?

Answer (score 32):

```
SELECT date, PhoneNumber, count(phone) AS count
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY date, PhoneNumber
```

should do it I think

Answer (score 9):

You may want to try something like

```
SELECT Date, Phone, Count(*) As Count From Calls GROUP BY Date, Phone
```

This will give you a tally of each phone number on each date, with how many times that number appeared on that date.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT date, phone, count(phone) AS count FROM calls GROUP BY date, phone
```

(You don't need DISTINCT with a GROUP BY.)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're grouping by *date* not by *phone*.

In one grouping of a date there may be three different numbers and it's impossible for SQL to know which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following

Count(phone) FROM calls

Will give you the Distinct Count.